# jquery datatable adding removed rocords to datatable again when add new data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery DataTables, I using ajax to add more rows to table using

```
 


     $.each(response.aaData, function (key, value) {
                                var TicketId = value[0];
                                var FullName = value[1];
                                var TicketName = value[2];
                                var ReferenceNo = value[3];
                                var StartDate = value[4];
                                var ExpiryDate = value[5];
                                var Status = value[6];
                                var UserId = value[7];

                                var rowNode = oDTable.row.add([
                                  TicketId,
                                   FullName,
                ' ' + TicketName,
                                  ReferenceNo,
                                  StartDate,
                                  ExpiryDate,
                                  "" + Status + "",
                                  UserId,

                                ]).draw().node();
```

It's adding rows perfectly..

I have single delete button to delete all the rows. Here I am using remove code

```
$('#EmployeesTicketsDT').on('click', 'tr.group button.del', function (e) {
        var confirm = window.confirm("This will remove usertickets from list, Do you want to   proceed?");
        if (confirm) {                                        $('#EmployeesTicketsDT').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.group').remove())
            $('#EmployeesTicketsDT').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr').remove())
        }
    });
```

It will remove all the rows under a particular group and stop if reach to next group.

But when i re-add the records it is adding double records one with ajax hit and other is old one...weired.

It should add only new records not old one...please help...

Comment: Are you using a server-side data source?

Comment: yes i am using server side data source but adding row using ajax with row.add() method of datatable.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time I got the solution of this problem,

I user

```
.empty()
```

instead of

```
.remove()
```

.

```
$('#EmployeesTicketsDT').on('click', 'tr.group button.del', function (e) {
        var confirm = window.confirm("This will remove usertickets from list, Do you want to   proceed?");
        if (confirm) {                                        $('#EmployeesTicketsDT').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.group').empty())
            $('#EmployeesTicketsDT').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr').empty())
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.  I'm surprised this isn't a more common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
"bDestroy" : true
```

in your datatable object init or alternatively you can

```
 $('yourtable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

and then recreate it.

Comment: I am already using "bDestroy":true, but it's not the solution. the problem is row.remove() remove all the rows. I have inspected the table body. There is no row after remove() but when i re-add new records it automatically append old records too...

Comment: one thing more i can't clear() or destroy() the datatable because it contains more than one groups and under each group there are rows. If i click delete on one group it remove only clicked group rows not other's..